# Any easy way to assign paginates to a button?

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I create a custom `<select>` in order to paginate the results, but I don't know how to make usable.

I want to do the easiest way to work, and in my brain is link the `paginate` method in `AlumnoController` with this `select` options.

Can I? Or it's harder than I want to do?

**EDIT:** Thanks for your help **@enrollment**!! This is how code is right now. I think it's close to work and I like very much this code, can you help me to finish it?

##### `web.php`

```
Route::resource('alumnos', AlumnosController::class);
Route::get('/alumnos?{paginateValue}', [AlumnosController::class, 'showPaginated'])->name('alumnos');
Route::post('/alumnos', [AlumnosController::class, 'update'])->name('update.paginateValue');
```

##### `AlumnosController.php`

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $alumnos = Alumnos::select('ALU_ID', 'ALU_NOMBRE', 'ALU_APELLIDO1', 'ALU_APELLIDO2')
                    ->orderBy('ALU_ID', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(10);

        return view ('alumnos.alumnos', compact('alumnos'));
    }
```

##### `index.blade.php`

```
    <table class="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre y apellidos</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach ($alumnos as $alumno)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $alumno->ALU_ID ?? '(Sin ID)' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $alumno->ALU_NOMBRE ?? '(Sin Nombre)' }} {{ $alumno->ALU_APELLIDO1 ?? '(Sin Apellido 1)' }} {{ $alumno->ALU_APELLIDO2 ?? '(Sin Apellido 2)' }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="footer-tools">
        @isset($paginateValue)
        <div class="pages">
            {{$alumnos->links()}}
        </div>
        @endisset

        <form action="{{route('update.paginateValue')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <select name="select" id="select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option>Filter by quantity</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Laravel documentation on pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination) . it addressed your challenge on creating pagination in blade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea is good. But you have to do more in controller and blade.

You can check here for simple example: http://novate.co.uk/allow-user-to-choose-pagination-length-via-dropdown-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your idea and trying to find a solution, I have achieved it in the following way:

When the user selects the number of students per page, the controller receives that number, and depending on whether it is shown in a different route, so as not to collide with the main "alumnos" route, I hope I have been able to help you.

**AlumnoController**

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $paginateValue = $request->select;
    switch ($paginateValue) {
        case '5':
            return redirect()->route('alumnos', [$paginateValue]);
        break;

        case '10':
            return redirect()->route('alumnos', [$paginateValue]);
        break;

        case '15':
            return redirect()->route('alumnos', [$paginateValue]);
        break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public function showPaginated($paginateValue){
    $alumnos = Alumnos::orderBy('NAME', 'asc')->paginate($paginateValue);
    return view('alumnos', compact('alumnos', 'paginateValue'));
}

public function index(){
    $alumnos = Alumnos::orderBy('NAME', 'asc')->paginate(15);
    return view('alumnos', compact('alumnos'));
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
  @foreach ($alumnos as $alumno)
        {{$alumno->name}}
  @endforeach

  {{$alumnos->links()}}
           
  <form action="{{route('update.paginateValue')}}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <select name="select" id="select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option>Filter by quantity</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
      </select>
  </form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/alumnos', [AlumnoController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/alumnos&{paginateValue}', [AlumnoController::class, 'showPaginated'])->name('alumnos');
Route::post('/alumnos', [AlumnoController::class, 'update'])->name('update.paginateValue');;
```

Comment: Wow man, this is a great solution! It doesn't work but I think we are close!! For some reason the web updates with the correct url, but don't paginate correctly and still appear paginated as the first version of index. LOOK THE MAIN MESSAGE, I UPDATE IT WITH YOUR CODE!

Comment: It didn't work as it was taking the default path by including the ? in the route, I have solved it by replacing it with an &, take a look again (change in web.php "/alumnos&{paginateValue")

Comment: I also made 2 more changes, at index.blade.php and controller, check the edit, hope it works now! :)